Spring Boot RabbitMQ: How to create per-instance auto-recovering queues in a cluster with proper cleanup on shutdown?
My Spring app (Spring Boot v3.3.2, Spring v6.1.11) runs in a cluster and I need to make it in a such way that each instance of the cluster can create it's own queue in RabbitMQ (3.12.13-management) on start up (e.g. during autoscaling or deployment events) with a unique name, and make it so that the queue is automatically deleted when the instance shuts down (or crushes). I tried using combinations of exclusive / auto-delete flags, but things don't always work well:
The problem
Sometimes (I assume during connection failure) queues are not recovered and I see Queue 'ccbbb452-6150-46e1-91dc-3b4fd8c1afaf' is still not available error in logs.
Here is the approach I used:
RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
// https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/broker-configuration.html#declarable-recovery
admin.setRedeclareManualDeclarations(true);
admin.afterPropertiesSet();

String queueName = genUUID();
Queue instanceSpecificQueue = new Queue(queueName, /*durable*/true, /*exclusive*/true, /*autodelete*/true);

admin.declareQueue(instanceSpecificQueue);

During manual tests I kill the connection using MQ Management API (to simulate connection failure), and it works fine - the queue is redeclared and the connection works again, but over a longer periods of observation it seems that there are still situations when it fails to reconnect and gives the above error Queue 'ccbbb452-6150-46e1-91dc-3b4fd8c1afaf' is still not available. Note that I do have setRedeclareManualDeclarations(true);
I found this https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/queues#shared-temporary-queues (RabbitMQ documentation suggests to use broker generated names because a race condition can happen with temporary queues, and it may get "Declared by the recovering client and then deleted" by MQ). However this approach does not work at all as when I delete the connection manually it's not recovering at all and just gives Failed to declare queue: amq.gen-rO3n2RJrniPE8RE3MCXsvw error.
